# Uppercasing first letter of a line after period in previous line

Tags: text-processing, sed, text-formatting, text

I have many little poems to edit like this:

```
Io avevo due sorelle,
una bionda e l’altra mora,
tutte e due leggiadre e belle
e gentil come l’aurora.
ma la bionda mi è sparita,
se ne è andata all’altra vita.
mi hanno detto che lassù
più risplende il suo bel viso
dove è gioia ed è sorriso
ma non tornerà mai più.
e la mora sta lontana,
nella terra pascoliana.
colgo e bacio il primo fiore:
il pensier quel bacio porta
su la viva e su la morta,
tutte e due lo stesso amore.
```

Italian grammar rules prescribe uppercase on first letter when a verse starts after that in previous verse there is a period. So it should be (see uppercase letter after period at line 5, for Instance)

```
Io avevo due sorelle,
una bionda e l’altra mora,
tutte e due leggiadre e belle
e gentil come l’aurora.
Ma la bionda mi è sparita,
se ne è andata all’altra vita.
Mi hanno detto che lassù
più risplende il suo bel viso
dove è gioia ed è sorriso
ma non tornerà mai più.
E la mora sta lontana,
nella terra pascoliana.
Colgo e bacio il primo fiore:
il pensier quel bacio porta
su la viva e su la morta,
tutte e due lo stesso amore.
```

I'm in trouble to do this with sed, how it can be solved? Of you know more proper ways than sed, I'm interested too

Answer (score 9):

GNU sed which has a uppercase feature \U

```
sed -e '
  $!N
  s/\.\n./\U&/
  P;D
' file
```

Answer (score 8):

Using Perl:

```bsh
perl -00 -pe 's/\.\n./\U$&/g' file
```

This reads the file a paragraph at a time (a paragraph is delimited by at least one empty line), and upper-cases any character occurring after a dot and a newline character.

Answer (score 7):

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/\.$/+1s/./\u&/' '%p' | ex file
```

- `g/\.$/` selects all lines with a trailing period.
- `+1s` Applies the following substitute command on the next line to each selected.
- [`\u` in the replacement slot uppercases the next character](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html#tag_20_40_13_59) and `&` is a meta-character for "whatever was matched by the regex".
- `%p` prints all the resulting lines.

##### Notes

- The command outputs the expected result in the standard output. To actually edit the file, use the "write and exit" command instead:

  ```
  printf '%s\n' 'g/\.$/+1s/./\u&/' x | ex file
  ```
- The `/\.$/` regex won't catch lines with blank spaces after a final period. To tackle that case, use `/\. *$/` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk 'prev ~ /\.$/{$0=toupper(substr($0,1,1)) substr($0,2)} {prev=$0} 1' file
Io avevo due sorelle,
una bionda e l’altra mora,
tutte e due leggiadre e belle
e gentil come l’aurora.
Ma la bionda mi è sparita,
se ne è andata all’altra vita.
Mi hanno detto che lassù
più risplende il suo bel viso
dove è gioia ed è sorriso
ma non tornerà mai più.
E la mora sta lontana,
nella terra pascoliana.
Colgo e bacio il primo fiore:
il pensier quel bacio porta
su la viva e su la morta,
tutte e due lo stesso amore.
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/\.$/{n;s/^[a-z]/\U&/}' input_file
Io avevo due sorelle,
una bionda e l’altra mora,
tutte e due leggiadre e belle
e gentil come l’aurora.
Ma la bionda mi è sparita,
se ne è andata all’altra vita.
Mi hanno detto che lassù
più risplende il suo bel viso
dove è gioia ed è sorriso
ma non tornerà mai più.
E la mora sta lontana,
nella terra pascoliana.
Colgo e bacio il primo fiore:
il pensier quel bacio porta
su la viva e su la morta,
tutte e due lo stesso amore.
```

Comment: This is flawed. What if there are consecutive lines ending with dots? Your `sed` code will alter every other line. In other words: the line you read with `n` may end with a dot, but the code does not take it into account.

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -e 'S:g/ \. $$ \n ^^ <(\w)> /{$/.uc}/.put given lines.join("\n");'
```

Sample Input:

```
"Le due sorelle"
(di Giuseppe Geri Gavinana)

Io avevo due sorelle,
una bionda e l’altra mora,
tutte e due leggiadre e belle
e gentil come l’aurora.
ma la bionda mi è sparita,
se ne è andata all’altra vita.
mi hanno detto che lassù
più risplende il suo bel viso
dove è gioia ed è sorriso
ma non tornerà mai più.
e la mora sta lontana,
nella terra pascoliana.
colgo e bacio il primo fiore:
il pensier quel bacio porta
su la viva e su la morta,
tutte e due lo stesso amore.
```

Sample Output:

```
"Le due sorelle"
(di Giuseppe Geri Gavinana)

Io avevo due sorelle,
una bionda e l’altra mora,
tutte e due leggiadre e belle
e gentil come l’aurora.
Ma la bionda mi è sparita,
se ne è andata all’altra vita.
Mi hanno detto che lassù
più risplende il suo bel viso
dove è gioia ed è sorriso
ma non tornerà mai più.
E la mora sta lontana,
nella terra pascoliana.
Colgo e bacio il primo fiore:
il pensier quel bacio porta
su la viva e su la morta,
tutte e due lo stesso amore.
```

Above is an answer coded in **Raku**, a member of the Perl family of programming languages. A few niceties of Raku include a new, more powerful regex engine, as well as graceful handling of Unicode built-in.

Briefly, `lines` are read lazily and (because the desired recognition sequence spans different lines), they are `join`-ed with `\n` to reconstruct the original input. Raku's non-destructive `S///` idiom is then used to recognize the first `^^` beginning-of-line `\w` character following a three-'atom' `\.` literal dot, `$$` end-of-line, `\n` newline sequence. Note regex 'atoms' can be freely separated by whitespace in the recognition (left) half of the `S///` operator. From here Raku's `<(...)>` match operator is used to drop everything from the `$/` match object variable outside of `\w`. In the replacement the `$/.uc` match object variable is uppercased, replacing the (lowercase) `/w` beginning-of-line character.

A few notes of interest, in true Perlish TMTOWTDI-spirit, the Raku code above can be written as follows, which returns the same output as above:

```perl
raku -e 'lines.join("\n").subst(:global, / \. $$ \n ^^ <(\w)> /, {$/.uc}).put;'
```

And if you just want to look at the recognition sequence *before* replacement, you can abstract out the `$/` match variable and `say` it (useful for refining your regex code). Below, Raku recognizes four (4) individual, beginning-of-line characters, poised for replacement:

```perl
raku -e 'say $/ given lines.join("\n").subst(:global, / \. $$ \n ^^ <(\w)> /, {$/.uc});'  file
(｢m｣ ｢m｣ ｢e｣ ｢c｣)
```

---

Note: a rough (working) Raku translation of the Perl5 code posted by @they might be:

```perl
raku -e 'for lines.join("\n") {S:g/\.\n./{$/.uc}/.put};'
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#S///_non-destructive_substitution
https://raku.org